# Au fur et à mesure

Tags: expressions, locutions

> Au fur et à mesure

Pourquoi dit-on *à mesure* et pas *à la mesure*, vue que au fur = à+le fur, non ?
Pourquoi pas *à fur et à mesure* ?

> L’expression "au fur et à mesure" double le sens de chaque terme ; "au
>   fur" et "à mesure" signifient la même chose. Ce pléonasme est consacré
>   par l’usage. L’usage de au fur et à mesure de quelque chose, est
>   considéré comme familier. ([wiki](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_fur_et_%C3%A0_mesure))

Est-ce vrai cela ? Je l'ai entendu même dans des présentations formelles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« au fur et à mesure » est une locution adverbiale, c'est à dire une forme figée, c'est pourquoi on n'en questionne pas le sens sur le plan des mots qui la constituent; « à mesure » signifie la même chose que « au fur et à mesure » pas la même chose que « au fur » qui n'est pas utilisé; voici ce que donne le TLFi sur « au fur » : Rem. Chez Claudel, arch. et littér. a) Au fur de, loc. prép. À mesure de, à proportion de.  « le pléonasme est consacré par l'usage » reviens à ce qui est dit ci-dessus : la forme est figée, on ne questionne pas les relations entre les  mots qui la constituent.
Il ne semble pas que l'usage de « au fur et à mesure » soit familier, cependant ; il n'est fait aucune mention de cela dans le TLFi.